# UIImageView does not stretch to whole screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, viewcontroller

I prototype an app and navigation and my UIImageView in ViewControllers, which I created in Storyboard (Xcode 6) does not stretch to full screen. For example, I have UIImageView with 640×1136 image. If I run it on iPhone 5, it shows me full screen. But if I run it on iPhone 6 or 6 Plus, it locates in top left corner. I read so many topics and articles, but nothing helped.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you read about Adaptive layouts?

Comment: What is the name of your image view?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure your `UIImage` is in an `UIImageView` and then either add constraints or change the content mode like this:

```
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Or change it in the story board in the attributes inspector under **view**.

[Here is a list of all the values you can set for this property.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewContentMode)

**Edit**: reading your issue over, I think you definitely need to add constraints to your view. There are lots of tutorials on how to do this: [here is apples.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html)

You add your constraints by clicking the pin menu, and then clicking on the four red brackets and clicking "Add Constraints".

[image]

Comment: I changed to Aspect Fit (and tried all modes), but it did not help me.

Comment: @AntonChuiko pin all four directions on your view and then play with the content mode too see which one gives you the image you're happiest with.

Comment: your apples link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

Just add aspectRatio constraint to imageView

Answer (score 0):

use AutoLayout and add all four constraint(top right,left,bottom) on it.